Expected payoff of two dice scenario
I've been given the following question:

You have two fair $10$-sided dice that are colored green and yellow with values $1$ to $10$ on each side. You roll both dice simultaneously. If they show the same value, then the game is over. If the two dice are not equal, but the yellow die shows a value at least $3$ larger than the green die, you receive $1 and can roll both dice again. In all other cases, you receive nothing and can roll again. The game only ends once the two dice show the same value. What is your expected payout on this game?

The provided solution sets up an equation
$$
E = (E-1) \cdot \frac{7}{25} + E \cdot \frac{31}{50}.
$$
I get that expectation is finite because we have conditions for termination, but how do you reach this equation in the first place?

Just consider the possible outcomes of each roll.

@user2661923  I didn't check the formula, you might be right.  The logic is the key point, I figured.

@user2661923 $E=(E+1)\times\frac{28}{100}+E\times\frac{62}{100}+0 \times \frac{10}{100}$ would help check the probabilities add up to $1$ and also make the calculation of $E \times \frac{10}{100} =\frac{28}{100}$ i.e. $E =\frac{28}{10}=2.8$ easier

@user2661923 I would read  "the yellow die shows a value at least 3 larger than the green die" as $Y \ge G+3$ rather than $Y \ge G\times 3$

@Henry You are right, my misread.  I will delete my comments.

The probability that the game ends immediately on the next roll is $\frac{1}{10}$ (where the dice match). For all other rolls, the game continues. The probability that we will gain $\$1$ before continuing is $\frac{\frac{1}{2} (1 + 7) (7)}{100} = \frac{7}{25}$. The other $1 - \frac{1}{10} - \frac{7}{25} = \frac{31}{50}$ is continuing without gaining anything.
So, if $E$ is the value of the game, we have that
$$E = \frac{1}{10} (0) + \frac{31}{50} E + \frac{7}{25} (E + 1)$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{10} E = \frac{7}{25} \implies \boxed{E = \frac{14}{5}}$$
Indeed, the given solution does not even make sense, because if you solve it, you will find that $E < 0$, which is not possible. The $E - 1$ was most likely a typo and should be $E \color{red}{ + } 1$.

$E=(E+1)\times\frac{28}{100}+E\times\frac{62}{100}+0 \times \frac{10}{100}$ would help check the probabilities add up to $1$ and also make the calculation of $E \times \frac{10}{100} =\frac{28}{100}$ i.e. $E =\frac{28}{10}=2.8$ easier.  You wrote $\frac9{10}E$ where you probably intended $\frac1{10}E$.

@Henry Yes, thank you.
